# Spark 1.5.0 spark.app.id warning

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-1.5

I had updated my CDH cluster to use `spark 1.5.0`. When I submit spark application, the system show warning about `spark.app.id`

```
Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
```

I have searched about `spark.app.id` but not document about it. I read this [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) and I think It is used for RestAPI call.

I don't see this warning in `spark 1.4`. Could someone explain it to me and show how to set it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not necessarily used for the REST API, but rather for monitoring purpose e. g when you want to check yarn logs per example:

```
yarn logs <spark.app.id>
```

It's true that this specific issue is still not documented yet. I think it's been added to standardize the application deployment within the Hadoop ecosystem.

I suggest that you set the 'spark.app.id' in your app.

```
conf.set("spark.app.id", <app-id>) // considering that you already have a SparkConf defined of course
```

Nevertheless, this remains a warning which won't effect the application itself.