# where to check my yarn+spark's applications' log?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh

I wrote an application with yarn+spark, for simplicity, I list the following

```
object testKafkaSparkStreaming extends Logging {

     private class Parser extends Logging{
       def parse(row: String): Row =
       {
         val row = "/_dc.gif| |20160616063934| |39.190.5.69| |729252016040907094857083a3c7c62e"

         logInfo("pengcz starting parse " + row)
       }
     }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
       ...
       logInfo("main starting parse " + row)
       ...
    }
}
```

When I executed:

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --class $CLASS $JAR ...
```

I can see the two log infos in the console

But when I executed:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --class $CLASS $JAR ...
```

And I opened the yarn web ui of my own application:

http://192.168.36.172:8088/cluster/app/application_1465894400511_3624
[image]
And I click `logs` under the page, I got:
[image]
But the page has not information including my two logs

What should I do to find my own logs? 
Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark 1.5.0 spark.app.id warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32793276/spark-1-5-0-spark-app-id-warning)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command to see the Yarn Logs of an Application :

```
yarn logs -applicationId <Your Yarn Application ID> // i.e. application_1465894400511_3624
```